# PHP: Find php token in file without parsing entire file with token_get_all

Tags: php, parsing, token

I need to parse PHP file looking for certain token.

It can be easly done with `$tokens = token_get_all($fileContent);` and then looking for required token in results array `$tokens`.

Problem is that for bigger files parsing takes even around `0.15s` while it's very likely that required token may be somewhere in beginning of file - in such case a lot of time lost for parsing is wasted.

Is it possible to make some kind of step by step token parsing and stopping parsing when required token was found?

Comment: chunk_split() ?  str_split() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen("myFile.php", "r");
while ( ($line = fgets($f)) != null) {
    $tokens = token_get_all ($line);
    if (in_array ($searchedToken, $tokens)) {
        // do your job...
        break; 
    }
}
fclose ($f);
```

Comment: Some tokens are multi line and it would create different result for such case

Comment: `token_get_all()` doesn't work with single lines of PHP, and doesn't always return an array.